# X11 doesn't show windows edges, task bar nor anything

Tags: xorg, lightdm

I've got a problem with X11 as when I turn on my computer, after the system has launched, I see only my desktop. I don't see the upper nor left bar. When I doubleclick a file on my desktop, a new windows show but it has no edges with buttons for closing, minimizing, maximizing, it is centered in the middle of the screen and it cannot be moved. Any work is impossible at all.

I don't even know how it could happen as I haven't been messing with any system files recently.

Comment: It sounds like you're using Ubuntu's default desktop environment, or were using it. Try pressing [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[T] and typing `unity&`. If this doesn't work, try `compiz --replace&`. The `&` signs make the specified commands run as background processes, but don't close out of the window/windows you typed this/these into. That will stop the desktop environment again, leaving you with your original problem. Granted, this is only a temporary fix, but at least it provides a sensible solution until something more permanent can be reached. As a last result, if nothing else works, do `sudo apt-get`...

Comment: ...`install unity`. If it says it's already installed, type `sudo dpkg-reconfigure unity`.

Comment: Have you tried answers here https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears

Comment: It's exactly what I have but I tried lot of these solutions and none of them worked. Majority gave of tons of error actually. I think I should some kinda reinstall, reset all Unity settings. I tried `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`, `unity --reset-icons &disown` but both command gave off errors. I've heard a good way to reset hardly Unity is to delete settings so they can regenerate. 
So, what should I do?
And can the problems be connected with nvidia drivers?

Answer (score -1):

Firat try:

```
sudo updatedb
```

If not working then try using metacity

```
sudo apt-get install metacity
metacity --replace&
```